# How to change the color of values & percentages in a pie chart's legend?

Tags: visualization, anylogic

I have set the `Text color:` field in my pie chart's legend to a custom color that fits well with my model's UI color scheme, however only the title labels had their colors changed, and the values/percentages are still the default blue color.

Is there any way to change the color of the values & percentages in a pie chart's legend?

[image: My Pie Chart]

I have tried looking through the functions in the pie chart's api, but so far I haven't found anything that could help me change the color of those text fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not.

However, you could create your own agent type `LegendEntry` and have full control over any visual aspect...

Or check out [this library](https://www.materialdesignforanylogic.com/optin1597310065044) that also has custom legend animations (full disclosure: I built it but I do not earn commission on it).